# Show sections with core data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I want to code a todo app and display 2 sections. 1 for entrys, that have to be done and 1 for already done things.
I want something like that:

```
    Things not done yet
    Todo 1
    Todo 2
    Things already done
    Todo 3
    Todo 4
```

At the moment I have 1 section for the undone todos. 
My code for the table view at the moment looks like this

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"To do",@"done",nil];

    return [array objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

And my code for the fetchedresultscontroller looks like this:

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Todo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"done == %@", @(NO)];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"done" cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
```

Objects with the key "NO" are not done and with the key "YES" are done. But I don't know how to display both values in different sections.

---

**Edit**

I found the solution to my problem…

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"done" cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

That solved this problem. But now sometimes an undone item shows up at done. 
Or if there are two done items they appear under "Todo"

```
    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Todo",@"Done",nil];

    return [array objectAtIndex:section];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Thats my actual code for that… 
Now it looks like that. Undone todo unchecked, done todo checked. http://img.xnmn.de/i/2353ad.png
But if I check undone todo as done, they both appear at "todo" http://img.xnmn.de/i/5edff4.png

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code looks almost right. Since you set the `sectionKeyPath` to "done", the fetched results controller will automatically create the sections for you. You could add another sort descriptor for the "done" attribute to sort the entries according to their section.

What you **have** to do is to remove the `NSPredicate`. In you current code, you're filtering out all entries with "done == YES", but since you have your two sections, you want the results controller to return all entries.

So basically you just need to remove the

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"done == %@", @(NO)];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Of course you'd also have to implement the `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: Oh, you're right. Could you explain me, what you mean with `Of course you'd also have to implement the – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method`? Because I'm new at iOS development

Comment: I mean you need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol's method `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Maybe take a look at [this tutorial](http://kurrytran.blogspot.de/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html) or the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I don't get it… My code for the method looks like that `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}` Could you please explain what I have to do in my case? I really don't understand it now…

Comment: That looks good. You didn't post the method in your question, so I wasn't sure you had implemented it. But since you obviously have done that, you should be good to go. Just remove the predicate from you results controller. (Be aware that the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method only works in iOS 6 and later.

Comment: But now it shows up all things in the todo section, not in the done section

Comment: hmm, have you tried adding a sort descriptor for "done"? And are the actually entries with "done == NO" in your data (somewhat obvious, but you never know^^)?

Comment: I've checked in my database are currently 2 undone and 1 done objects.

Comment: I tried this `NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
 NSSortDescriptor *statusDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"done" ascending:YES];
 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, statusDescriptor, nil];
 [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
` But it doesn't changes anything

Answer (score 1):

If i get your Code right you already created the section which is fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)inTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *identifier = @"Entry";
UITableViewCell *cell = [inTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
YourObject *cellEntry = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//init cell
}
```

This should choose the right entry for the right section otherwise the line where you set the section is wrong.

The index path chooses the right section.